# Is the observed speed of an infinite set of perfect ocean waves of constant amplitude and frequency independent of an observer's motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, phase-velocity

I am asking this question because it occurred to me that wave propagation has some generally under considered properties regardless and independent of the medium in which the waves are propagating. For instance, we observe ocean waves and perceive that the waves themselves are moving but as we know in reality, they do not move. Since they do not move in the normal sense there can be no relative motion between an observer and a propagating ocean wave, as counter intuitive as that seems. A propagating ocean wave does not move in the normal sense as does a boat moving across the surface of the water for instance. That being the case then the frame of reference in which an observer observes the speed of propagating ocean waves is irrelevant. In answering the important aspect of this question, it is appropriate and reasonable to assume the following:

1. The hypothetical ocean is lossless,
2. Waves are of constant amplitude and frequency propagating in given direction only and,
3. The propagation speed as measured in an inertial reference is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Wave in ocean (like any waves) are characterized by a *phase velocity* which humans perceives as the velocity of waves moving (note that I am talking here about waves far from the shore, not the waves that we see on a beach, where the matter actually moves in horizontal direction.)

Observer may perceive the velocity of waves as different from their velocity in respect to the ocean bed due to the [Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) - if the observer is moving towards or opposite the waves direction.

Answer (score -1):

From stationary vantage point waves are observed propagating @ 100cm/s. Wavelength observed = 100cm. Wave frequency is 1Hz. We now move @ 100cm/s parallel to propagation direction in the opposite direction. Observed frequency is 2Hz.  Observed wavelength contracts to 50cm. Wave period calculated is 0.5s. Propagation speed calculated using Distance/Time e.g., Wavlength / Wave Period. 50cm/0.5s = 100cm/s = Observed propagation speed from a stationary vantage point.

If I am correct, this observation extends to the observed constancy of EM propagation speed in vacuum or in any other medium.

Comment: What you say of the observed wavelength contracting is incorrect. Wavelength in invariant under Galilean transformations (and the difference between Galilean and Lorentz transformations is negligible at $v=1\mathrm{ m/s}$. For $\lvert v\rvert/c\ll1$ you can simply add velocities.

Comment: Such is not the case in the example. When observing the wave stream whilst in motion as described you cannot deny the frequency change! E.g. Doppler effect. If the observed frequency increases, clearly the 'observed' wavelength is reduced. It is halved in the simple example I provided.  Ignoring the 'C' question for the moment what is it that is incorrect in the ocean wave example stated?

Comment: I didn't say anything about frequency (the frequency change you stated is correct). However, a change in the frequency does not imply a change in the wavelength. For example, consider what would happen if you instead moved at $100\mathrm{ cm/s}$ in the same direction as the wave. In this case, the frequency would be 0, meaning that the wavelength would need to become infinite for the speed to be invariant as you suggest, which you can easily see to not be the case by simply measuring the distance between two crests. Distance (incl. wavelength) is an invariant quantity in Galilean relativity.

Comment: We know from observation that the frequency of observed light varies if a source is receding or approaching at sufficient speed. E.g., emission line frequency shifts. Clearly the observed frequencies and therefore wavelengths observed change when either the source or the observer is in motion. Based on this, I do not understand your response and it would be appreciated if could elaborate.

Comment: Ah yes I love the example you cited of moving in the same direction at the same speed as the propagating, ocean wave in this case, wave. It is very clear that in this case, yes you will observe a stationary lump of water apparently defying the laws of physics as we know them, and yes the 'observed' wavelength in that is infinite. What is the problem with that. It is the physical reality of this little mind experiment.

Comment: It is not possible for observed frequency to change if observed wavelength did not also change for the observer in motion. It makes no sense. They are related and inseparable. From the perspective of the underlying reality, no the wavelength of the propagating wave as observed by a stationary observer is still the original 100cm in my example. But for the observer in motion that is certainly not the case.

Comment: The invariance of the speed of light waves comes from a special property of the speed of light. More generally, the 4-velocity of a wave transforms according to Lorentz transformations (which, for $\lvert v\rvert/c\ll1$ is well-approximated by simply adding the 3-velocities). I did not intend my example to be mind-boggling—just imagine yourself walking along a canal, comoving with the waves in it. Velocity is not frame invariant—the *speed of light* is.

Comment: A simple mind experiment:  Observer is moving opposite to the direction of propagation parallel to the plane of propagation @100cm/s 'beside' the passing waves observing perpendicular to the wave plane of oscillation. Hold a 1m ruler up to the wave stream and snap a photo. Examine the photo. The wavelength measured is 50cm. We know this for certain because 'time' has not altered and so if observed frequency has altered then observed / measured wavelength has altered in our moving frame of reference.

Comment: "The invariance of the speed of light waves comes from a special property of the speed of light". I do not believe that is the case at all and I believe that there is a great misinterpretation of the theory that has been had. The speed of ALL propagating waves is invariant in any medium regardless of the frame of reference of an observer. My original example is just one example however, because of the underlying reason for this which I believe I understand very clearly, such is the case.

Comment: That is not to say, that the speed of ocean waves does not vary, we know that is not the case. It is the invariance of the 'observed' speed of propagation that I am talking about.

Comment: *Hold a 1m ruler up to the wave stream and snap a photo. Examine the photo. The wavelength measured is 50cm.* This is blatantly wrong, and easily testable. You need to understand that there isn't really any fundamental difference between the distance between the crests of the wave and the distance between the ends of the ruler—they both transform in the exact same way (which is negligible, in this case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144874/discussion-between-user3175893-and-sandejo).